# Universal algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, universal-algebra

I don't know the usual name for this (sub-)field of maths, but basically I'm talking about the study of algebraic geometry over general algebraic structures, in the sense of universal algebra. I think that field is specifically restricted to studying "equational Noetherian structures".

My questions are the following: what is this field precisely about, what are its paradigmatic questions? What are some examples of interesting results? 
Can anyone also provide references about it?

Comment: It seems that a relevant reference is [this paper in the arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3562) by Daniyarova et al., and its model theoretic preliminaries are in [this other paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.2522). Also there are some [Nullstellensatz](http://logica.dmi.unisa.it/lucaspada/tag/hilbert-nullstellensatz/) results in universal algebra by Spada et al.

Comment: Thanks, those references seem great !